# issues with my jquery validation added method password rule

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-validate

I want to do is make a password rule method in jquery validation to check if the user meet the requirements.

The user should put a password atleast 10 combination of numbers, letters and punctuation marks like (& and !)

My problem is the password is still valid even the user only put letters and numbers no punctuation marks.

```
password: {
                minlength:10,
                pwcheck: true,
                required: true
            },
```

check passoword method

```
$.validator.addMethod("pwcheck", function(value) {
    return /^[A-Za-z0-9\d=!\-@._*]*$/.test(value)
    && /[a-z]/.test(value) 
    && /\d/.test(value) 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression should look something like this (in this case, between 10 and 20 characters)

```
/^(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{10,20}$/
```

It uses a positive lookahead assertion - `(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])` - to ensure the string has at least one of these special characters.